# Saving the data in database in windows phone 7.1

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

Saving the data in database in windows phone 7.1 
Best way to do this . How to use sqlite. How to do this using only sqlite and using linq also.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link on how to use [Sqlite in Windows phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx).

And check this for [Local database support in Windows Phone 7](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-24-local.html) and [Linq based local database](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/corrado/archive/2011/06/05/using-local-database-in-wp7-mango.aspx) for other options.

Comment: which gives error ? on which database ? what is the code you tried ?
Please update your question with some code so that I can suggest some solution

Comment: I used this link [Sqlite in Windows phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx) I used this code to save my form and followed all the steps but it gave me the error "Cannot open database file".   Thanks in advance

Comment: It is giving me this error "Error 3 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'? E:\Work Area\Harshal\MobileApps\Experiment\dbSQLite\dbSqlite\dbSqlite\FillForm.xaml.cs 51 56 dbSqlite"  I already have system.core reference added. I have also tried by removing and adding the reference again in seperate project.

Comment: What is the code at the 51'st line of your FillForm.xaml.cs ?